# Python get substrings inbetween tags

Tags: python, base64, pipe

I’m trying to get data from a pipe in Python.
The data is structured like this:

```
<item><type> data </type><code> data </code><length> data </length><data encoding=“base64”> data </data></item>
```

How do I get the data inbetween these tags? I've already written a Base64 decoder.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow! Could you also post the code you currently have? This can help us answer your question. Or push you in the right direction.

Comment: What is this, XML? HTML? Use a parser.

Comment: Why did you write a base64 encoder? There is a library for that.

Comment: One of the options I was going to use was just to treat the string as a list and get the data based on it's position in the string, like "metadata[12:25]"

Comment: but the problem is the last two are variable lengths.

Comment: Also, the "shairport-sync-metadata-reader" on GitHub uses the sscanf function, but it's written in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the lxml package and treat the raw data as a html

```
from lxml import html

raw_data = '<item><type> data </type><code> data </code><length> data </length><data encoding=“base64”> data </data></item>'
html_data = html.fromstring(raw_data)

data = html_data.xpath('//text()')

# data = [' data ', ' data ', ' data ', ' data ']
```

that may be a bit overkill, another way is using regular expression

pattern copied from https://kevin.deldycke.com/2008/07/python-ultimate-regular-expression-to-catch-html-tags/

```
import re

def get_data(text):
    pattern = "(?i)<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>"
    return re.sub(p, '', text).split()

text = '<item><type> data </type><code> data </code><length> data </length><data encoding=“base64”> data </data></item>'
print(get_data(text))

# ['data', 'data', 'data', 'data']
```

Comment: Thanks! Installed libxml2-dev and libxslt1-dev, and found lxml in the apt repos. Pip version wouldn't install properly.